# Open Google Spreadsheet via Google Apps Script after creating a copy

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a copy of my google spreadsheet, and now want to close the current spreadsheet and open the one i created a copy. I know i can open it using the sheet id, but i dont know the sheet id yet because I want to achieve this using one macro!
current code -

```
function saveAsSpreadsheet(){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); 
  DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy("Test File", destFolder); 
  //want to open this copied file
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By modified your code a little bit, then you can obtain the copy sheet Id with `newsheet.getId()` function:

```
function saveAsSpreadsheet(){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxV6N-A4Z77f9OijHtAe2VhAU"); 
  var newsheet = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy("Test File", destFolder); 
  Logger.log(newsheet.getId())
}
```